# How to configure Redis Kubernetes deployment to make slave redis pod takeover when master is down?

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, redis

I have followed a [tutorial](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateless-application/guestbook/) to deploy Redis master and slave deployment. 
Both slave and master have its own services. I have Spring boot app that has master host in its configuration to save/read the data from it.
So when I terminate redis-master pod the Spring boot app is going down as it doesn't know that it should connect to slave. How to solve that? 
I was thinking about creating a common service for both master and slave, but this way the spring boot app will at some point try to save data to a slave pod instead of master.

Answer (score 2):

Use StatefulSets for redis deployment In HA. Use sentinel as sidecar container to manage failover